# function storing messages in a 2d array (in C programming)

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, multidimensional-array

What I want to achieve is a C program that stores names every time the user enters a name like the following:

func1:
read: john

func2
print john

func1:
read: michael

func2
print: john
print: michael

I want to know how to do this in 2 functions and not a single function.

- I have 2 function.
- function 1 
    -reads messages inputed by the user.(max number of 5 messages)

.

```
void read(void)
{
    int i;

    char read[100];
    // char * msg = (char *) malloc(sizeof(msg));

    //i want to read 5 messages from user
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",&read); 
        //i want to copy the message read into a variable msg, 
        //i dont know why i am doing this
        //strcpy(msg,read);
        //i want to call the store funcion 
        store(read);
    }
}
```

- function 2

  - it is called in function1's loop to read 5 mesaages
  - takes messages and passes it to its parameter
  - it stores message in a 2d array
  - prints entire 2d array

.

```
int store(char *stock)
{
    printf("saving.....stored\n");
    char share[5][10]; //this is my 2d array to hold 5 
                       //messages/names of 10 chars long
    int i=0;

    char * savedmsg = (char *) malloc(sizeof(savedmsg));
    strcpy(share[i],stock); 

    printf("%s\n",share[i]);
    i++; 
    printf("%s\n", share[1]);
}
```

I have started learning C this week but I presume the error I am getting is that func2 keeps re-initializing `i=0;` where I want it to increment `i++;` so func2 keeps overwriting the first index in 2d array.

Thanks for future help.

Comment: `i=i++` is undefined behavior. `i++` will increment `i`.

Comment: `i++` or `i = i + 1`, but not `i = i++`.  You are also haemorrhaging memory by `malloc`ing memory then discarding the reference to it without `free`ing.  You are not even using the allocated memory.  You should also check `i < 5` before writing to `share[]`.  `share[]` can only store strings of length 9, because strings have a nul terminator character appended. You also have no guarantee the user will enter fewer than 9 characters - it will be very easy to crash this code by user input.

Comment: `sizeof(savedmsg)` is the size of a `char*` pointer - it seems unlikely you intend that, even if you are to use `savedmsg` somehow.  In C it is best not to cast the return from malloc - a `void*` can safely be assigned to any other pointer type.

Comment: its supposed to be "i++;" i inputted a wrong line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```
int i=0;
```

declare it as `static` like this:

```
static int i=0;
```

The value of `i` is saved during function call.